# Create an installer with Wix that downloads the files from JFrog Artifactory

Tags: wix, windows-installer, artifactory

I want to create an installer using Wix where the files are located in the JFrog Artifactory (where I can download through rest calls or using the jfrog.exe client). To be able to download those files the user might need to provide the login information.
The msi should not contain the files but download during the installation.
Does someone knows how to do it? Is there another solution without Wix for it?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can turn on anonymous access to  the repos you want the installer to download from. refer this: https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-can-i-allow-anonymous-user-access-to-specific-repositories-only/

Comment: I end up crating an installer from scratch.

Comment: @L.Sidney What happened with Wix Toolset? Didn't it support such functionality?